# systemd fails to restart service on-failure

Tags: systemd

I have a service file named refreshPacman.service which runs `pacman -Sy` once on boot. However since `After=network-online.target` only accounts for my connection to the router (and not my VPN) pacman will fail to connect to the mirrors. I tried solving this originally by using a `refreshPacman.timer` that would simply wait 60 seconds after `network-online.target`, but this would lead to pacman either refreshing once my laptop's already way past logging in (too slow for my liking), or fail if I for some reason forgot how to type.

I was trying to create a better solution by modifying my previous service file, which would have systemd try to load the service some amount of times before either succeding or giving up. After failing to get my service to work I currently have this:

```
[Unit]
Description=refreshes pacman's database
Wants=network-online.target
Wants=mullvad-daemon.service
After=network-online.target
After=mullvad-daemon.service

StartLimitIntervalSec=180s
StartLimitBurst=3

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pacman -Sy
RemainAfterExit=true

StandardOutput=journal

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To my understanding, this should:

```markdown
1. run the `ExecStart` once, (fail)
2. wait `RestartSec` seconds, (maby fail?)
3. repeat step 2 `StartLimitBurst` number of times
```

However according to both `journalctl -u refreshPacman.service -b` and `/var/log/pacman.log` the refresh command is only ever run once before giving up. I have made sure to disable & re-enable the service after updating it's contents (in case systemd doesn't like me editing the file the symling points to) but I can't get it to ever work. I still have a very limited understanding of how systemd works in general, so I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how on-failure or restarting works in general.

#### edit

I was messing around with a different service file, for some reason updating the timings to:

```
# nothing changed here

StartLimitIntervalSec=120s
StartLimitBurst=12

# nothing changed here

RestartSec=10s
```

allowed the service to work properly. I guess I was using such bloated timers for my testing that by the time I opened up the log file it still hadn't reloaded...

#### edit 2

I can't select my answer so IDK how to close this issue.

Comment: perhaps you need to `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: I tried it & still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

systemd was (probably) waiting too long to restart the task (answering so I can close the issue)